# How to escape double quotes inside PostgreSQL user defined type in COPY command

Tags: postgresql, escaping, postgresql-copy

I have problem with escaping some characters (for example double qoutes) inside COPY command. I am migrating older Oracle database to PostgreSQL 11.7. In Oracle database are **user defined types** and I am migrating these types into PostgreSQL user defined type equivalents, e.g.:

```
create type udt_type as
(
x double precision,
y double precision,
rotation double precision,
width double precision,
height double precision,
justification integer,
font varchar(255),
text varchar(1000)
);
```

If I create COPY command, it looks something like this:

```
COPY tablename (UDT_COLUMN) FROM stdin WITH NULL 'NULL' DELIMITER '|' ;
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,Some text 2")
```

Double quotes here should be mark for inches but I am not able to insert value correctly, because every time I escape double quotes, PostgreSQL double the character and it results in `""`.

I tried a lot of other version:

```
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,Some text 2")
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,"Some text 2""")
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,Some text 2\")
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,"Some text 2\"")
...
```

Results in:

```
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,"Some text 2""")
```

How can I escape character correctly. I can't even change the value manually in DataGrip or pgadmin without the `Unexpected end of input` error. Escaping works correctly in INSERTs but the behaviour of user defined types in COPY is different.

**EDIT**

With single quoutes it is not working:

```
COPY tablename (UDT_COLUMN) FROM stdin WITH NULL 'NULL' DELIMITER '|' ;
(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,'Some text 2"')
```

Error:

```
psql:tablename.sql:3: ERROR:  malformed record literal: "(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,'Some text 2"')"
DETAIL:  Unexpected end of input.
CONTEXT:  COPY tablename, line 1, column udt_column: "(707141.392,235754.051,6.283185,,,0.0,,'Some text 2"')"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quotes, just be sure your strings are properly enclose with single quotes. Within single quotes a double quote is just another character like any other.

Comment: Check the edit, it is not working